# Uploading App bundle in play store failed

Tags: flutter, android-12

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

[image]

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions on the link provided in the message you received?

Comment: Yes, tried but not working. Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the below line in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
android:exported="true"
```

[image]

Comment: Added that too In the manifest... but still, the same error persists... Is any other solution available?

Comment: Do  you  use  Receiver in your app ?

Comment: May I know your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion  ?

Comment: or just share me your manifest file

Comment: I did not use the receiver. Kindly check the manifest file https://ctxt.io/2/AABg9lYSEw

Comment: kindly set all your android:exported="true" 
at the line no. 24,31,34

Comment: make all of your android:exported="false" into true

Comment: Tried that too but not working.... :(

Comment: Ohhh sad ):  @DivyalakshmiY. If I find any soluntion I will share with you, But this is what worked for me